# ASP.Net Web API 2 Controller Unit Test Get Request Item Count

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq, xunit

I am trying to develop an Xunit test to establish if my Controller under test is returning the correct number of objects.

The Controller's `getAreas` function is as follows:

```
[HttpGet()]
public IActionResult GetAreas()
{
    _logger.LogTrace("AreasController.GetAreas called.");

    try
    {
        // Create an IEnumerable of Area objects by calling the repository.
        var areasFromRepo = _areaRepository.GetAreas();

        var areas = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<AreaDto>>(areasFromRepo);

        // Return a code 200 'OK' along with an IEnumerable of AreaDto objects mapped from the Area entities.
        return Ok(areas);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Failed to get all Areas: {ex}");

        return StatusCode(500, "An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later.");
    }

}
```

My test class uses Moq to mock the Logger, Repository and AutoMapper. I have created a variable to hold a list of objects to be returned by my mock repository:

```
private List<Area> testAreas = new List<Area>()
{
    new Area
    {
        Id = new Guid("87d8f755-ef60-4cfa-9a4a-c94cff9f8a22"),
        Description = "Buffer Store",
        SortIndex = 1
    },
    new Area
    {
        Id = new Guid("19952c5a-b762-4937-a613-6151c8cd9332"),
        Description = "Fuelling Machine",
        SortIndex = 2
    },
    new Area
    {
        Id = new Guid("87c7e1d8-1ce7-4d8b-965d-5c44338461dd"),
        Description = "Ponds",
        SortIndex = 3
    }
};
```

I created my test as follows:

```
[Fact]
public void ReturnAreasForGetAreas()
{
    //Arrange
    var _mockAreaRepository = new Mock<IAreaRepository>();
    _mockAreaRepository
        .Setup(x => x.GetAreas())
        .Returns(testAreas);

    var _mockMapper = new Mock<IMapper>();

    var _mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger<AreasController>>();
    var _sut = new AreasController(_mockAreaRepository.Object, _mockLogger.Object, _mockMapper.Object);

    // Act
    var result = _sut.GetAreas();

    // Assert
    Assert.NotNull(result);
    var objectResult = Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result);
    var model = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IEnumerable<AreaDto>>(objectResult.Value);
    var modelCount = model.Count();
    Assert.Equal(3, modelCount);
}
```

The test fails on the final `Assert`, it gets 0 when expecting 3.

The `result` is not `null`. The `objectResult` is an `OkObjectResult`. The `model` is an `IEnumerable<AreaDto>`, however it contains 0 items in the collection.

I can't see where I am going wrong here. Do I have to configure the mocked Automapper mapping?

Comment: you need to setup the mapper mock to return your desired result when invoked. Right now it is not setup so will default to empty collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to configure the mocked Automapper mapping

**Yes**

Setup the mapper mock to return your desired result when invoked. Right now it is not setup so will default to empty collection.

Create a collection to represent the DTOs

```
private List<AreaDto> testAreaDTOs = new List<AreaDto>()
{
    new AreaDto
    {
        Id = new Guid("87d8f755-ef60-4cfa-9a4a-c94cff9f8a22"),
        Description = "Buffer Store",
        SortIndex = 1
    },
    new AreaDto
    {
        Id = new Guid("19952c5a-b762-4937-a613-6151c8cd9332"),
        Description = "Fuelling Machine",
        SortIndex = 2
    },
    new AreaDto
    {
        Id = new Guid("87c7e1d8-1ce7-4d8b-965d-5c44338461dd"),
        Description = "Ponds",
        SortIndex = 3
    }
};
```

Any update the test to use that collection when the mocked mapped is invoked.

```
[Fact]
public void ReturnAreasForGetAreas()
{
    //Arrange
    var _mockAreaRepository = new Mock<IAreaRepository>();
    _mockAreaRepository
        .Setup(x => x.GetAreas())
        .Returns(testAreas);

    var _mockMapper = new Mock<IMapper>();
    //Fake the mapper
    _mockMapper
        .Setup(_ => _.Map<IEnumerable<AreaDto>>(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<Area>>()))
        .Returns(testAreaDTOs);

    var _mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger<AreasController>>();
    var _sut = new AreasController(_mockAreaRepository.Object, _mockLogger.Object, _mockMapper.Object);

    // Act
    var result = _sut.GetAreas();

    // Assert
    Assert.NotNull(result);
    var objectResult = Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result);
    var model = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IEnumerable<AreaDto>>(objectResult.Value);
    var modelCount = model.Count();
    Assert.Equal(3, modelCount);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, and concise.